# How do I clean up multiple Python versions and libraries on my Mac for optimal VSCode compatibility?

Tags: python, pandas, macos, visual-studio-code

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUlzW.png)I am a new Mac user and in the process of setting up my Air M1 for writing Python code, I have tried many different IDEs along with many different installations of Python.

For example, I remember initially going with Anaconda. Then I've tried PyCharm. Then I did a couple of pip installs, then a Homebrew install. Then finally settled with VSCode.

The last thing I did is that I installed Python with pyenv using `pyenv install python` and because it was not working, I tried `brew install python`. Then I copied the path command from the terminal to the .bash_profile and now when I type `python --version` in terminal it gives me the correct version which is 3.11.3.

Then, I went in VSCode, which was working well a couple of days ago and now it wouldn't work, and tried to run a piece of code for a university assignment that I used to run without problems, only to get a 'no module named pandas'. Then, in VSCode's terminal, I did pip install pandas, and now everything is working again.

Sorry for the complicated explanation, TLDR my problem is that I think I have lots of different versions of Python along with libraries (remember installing pandas successfully at least 4 times). I want to do a clean up of unwanted Python versions along with unwanted libraries, also maybe removed unwanted stuff from PATH, but don't know how.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is a screenshot of echo $PATH.

[image]

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Taking deleting Python 3.7 as an example:

1. Delete the Python 3.7 framework, open the terminal, and enter

   ```bash
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7
   ```
2. Delete Python 3.7 application directory

   ```bash
   cd /Applications
   sudo rm -rf Python 3.7
   ```
3. Delete the connection to Python 3.7 in the `/usr/local/bin` directory

   ```bash
   cd /usr/local/bin/
   ls -l /usr/local/bin
   rm theConnectionToPython3.7
   ```
4. Delete Python's environment path

   ```bash
   vi ~/.bash_profile
   ```
5. Confirm if Python has been deleted

   ```bash
   python3.7
   ```